# Can I Import Android Map Extensions in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-maps-v2, android-maps-extensions

Android Map Extensions Library had been containing the gradle for references, There is no bin to add it directly as library in Eclipse, I try to paste those files into the same package name in Eclipse but it does not work and gave many errors.

Is there any way i can Import Android Map Extensions in Eclipse.

Comment: What errors did you get exactly when copying sources? Did you also add resource files from AME?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `play-services` library you can locate it inside your sdk directory as shown in the figure below

[image]

Go to your sdk -> extras -> google -> m2repository -> to play-services -> go inside the version you'd like to use, you'll find an `.aar` file, copy that and rename the extension to `.jar`

If you'd like to add other repos you could browse through [maven](http://search.maven.org/) or [jcenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) (depending on where the project is uploaded) download the `.aar` file and repeat the same process.

If you were looking for the android map utils, here the [link](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.androidmapsextensions%7Candroid-maps-extensions%7C2.2.0%7Caar).

Comment: I think he is asking for AME found here: https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions I am having the same issue... importing is not working in eclipse.

Comment: You could have a look at the link i posted there, and download the .aar and use it as a jar?

Comment: Yes, that is googles map utilities, not android map extensions as the OP is asking about...

Comment: @jasonflaherty oh, sorry my bad. http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.androidmapsextensions%7Candroid-maps-extensions%7C2.2.0%7Caar will this link be useful then? You could use the .aar from here ?

Comment: @jasonflaherty yes you are right, i am talking about github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions

Comment: The Library name is Android Maps Extensions as we can see on the link

Comment: @Mohit checkout my edited link? let me know if it helps

Comment: OK @RakeebRajbhandari i will try that and let you inform, and Thanks for help